# Needing Assistance with vb.NET Application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I don't normally post on forums because I try to find information for myself, and ask as an absolute last resort. I've tried scouring the net for answers, but I'm only receiving about half of the answer I'm looking for.

I'm currently building an application that deals with state law.  There's one combo box and one text box. One for the offense title, and one for the numerical code for that particular code section. So say if I select "Kidnapping", it prepopulates the text box below it with "11-5-77", for example.

The method I've been using for, oh, about the last hour now, is:

```
If AWOffenseTitle.Text = "Kidnapping" Then
        AWCN.Text = "11-5-77"
    ElseIf AWOffenseTitle.Text = "False Imprisonment" Then
        AWCN.Text = "11-5-78"
```

With AWOffenseTitle being the combo box name, and AWCN being the text box name. While this has proved to work perfectly well so far, I'm sure you can imagine with hundreds of offense titles, this is going to take a ridiculously long time. Well, I finally found a spreadsheet with offense titles and their respective title codes. What I'm looking to do is create two text files within a folder in the local directory "Offenses". One with a vertical list of offenses, and one with a vertical list of offense code numbers that populate the same lines in each.  What I'm looking to do is populate the combo box with the contents of text file one (which I can do already), but then selecting an offense title will read the second text file and display it's proper title code. That's what has me at a loss.  I'm relatively well-versed with vb.NET, but I'm not an expert by any means.

I'm hoping someone here will be able to provide a code example and explain it to me line-by-line so I can gain a better understanding. I want to get more proficient with VB although it's not so popular anymore. I've been using VB since 6.0, but not on a regular basis. More on a sporadic project kind of basis.

I really appreciate any assistance anyone might be able to provide, and if you need more information, I'd be glad to answer any questions. I tried to be as thorough as I could.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Put your data into some data structure, and query/create a List(Of) that structure. Then, you can bind the ComboBox to that List. Utilize the ComboBox's DisplayMember and ValueMember properties, so when the offence Title is selected (DisplayMember), you can retrieve the offense code (ValueMember).

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to retrieve your data. I demonstrated using an Sql Server database containing a table named Offenses with columns named OffenseTitle and OffenseCode. You will have to change this code to match your situation.

```
Private Function GetOffenseData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select OffenseTitle, OffenseCode From Offenses;")
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

As the Form loads, set the properties of the ComboBox. DisplayMember matches the name of the title column and ValueMember is the name of the code column.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt = GetOffenseData()
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "OffenseTitle"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "OffenseCode"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Then when the selected item in the combo changes, just set the `.Text` property of `TextBox` to the `SelectedValue` in the combo and your code appears.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    TextBox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString
End Sub
```

There are other ways to do this if your data source is other than a database. Please advise if you need additional help.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [HardCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62477/hardcode)'s comment and [Mary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8367626/mary)'s detailed answer, I can only add an answer that's somewhere in between them.

It might be the case, that the information is not taken from a database, but from another source, like a text/data file or a web service. So it might be useful to create an abstraction for the data source you actually use.

First, I create a class or struct that will hold the data for each combo box item.

```
Class Offense
    Public ReadOnly Property Title As String
    Public ReadOnly Property Code As String

    Public Sub New(title As String, code As String)
        Me.Title = title
        Me.Code = code
    End Sub
End Class
```

Next, you need a method that retrieves a list of offenses that you can bind to your combo box. It's entirely up to you how you fill/fetch the offenses list. I have simply hard coded your two values here.

```
Private Function GetOffenseData() As List(Of Offense)
    Dim offenses As New List(Of Offense)

    offenses.Add(New Offense("Kidnapping", "11-5-77"))
    offenses.Add(New Offense("False Imprisonment", "11-5-78"))

    Return offenses
End Function
```

At a certain moment (probably in your form's Load event handler), you need to initialize your combo box. Just like Mary did, I use data binding.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AWOffenseTitle.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    AWCN.ReadOnly = True

    AWOffenseTitle.DisplayMember = NameOf(Offense.Title)
    AWOffenseTitle.ValueMember = NameOf(Offense.Code)
    AWOffenseTitle.DataSource = GetOffenseData()
End Sub
```

Note that I use the `NameOf` operator to get the desired property names of the `Offense` class. If you ever decide to rename the properties of your `Offense` class, you will be able to easily detect where they are used, since the compiler will complain if your code still uses the wrong property names somewhere.

Finally, the app needs to react to combo box value changes, so that the text box will show the corresponding offense code. Mary used an event handler for the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event, but I use a handler for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event instead:

```
Private Sub AWOffenseTitle_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AWOffenseTitle.SelectedIndexChanged
    AWCN.Text = AWOffenseTitle.SelectedValue
End Sub
```

(Up to now, I was not aware of the `SelectionChangeCommitted` event of the ComboBox control. I will need to look into this event to see if it is actually a better choice for this scenario, but I found that the `SelectedIndexChanged` event does the job just fine, so for now I sticked with that event, since I am more familiar with it.)